# why does this == Window?

Tags: javascript

In browser (Chrome) javascript:

```
var DataModler = {
    Data: { Something: 'value' },

    Process: function() { alert('not implemented.'); },
    Render: function() { alert('not implemented.'); }
}

DataModler.Process = function() {
    // do some data processing, then render it.
    this.Render();   // this == Window, so an exception is thrown.
};

DataModler.Render = function() {
    // render the data.
};
```

The problem I'm having is, if I set a breakpoint in `DataModler.Process()`, `this` is set to `Window`.  I expect `this` to be set to the object that defines the function, which to my mind is `DataModler`.  If I implement the function within the definition of `DataModler`, then `this == DataModler` as I would expect.

So I suppose the question is, how can I allow a function on my object to be replaced but still have `this` refer to the object on which the function is defined (`DataModler`)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @Chase The `this` keyword is a very convenient tool. It can be confusing for beginners, but it allows for much less clumsy code than the alternative.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I haven't done many of projects that need to create different objects from same class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in c69's comment, you are experiencing this problem due to how the function is actually called.
You can write

```
DataModler.Process = function() {
     ...
}.bind(DataModler);
```

to ensure that `this` withing `Process` is `DataModler`.

Comment: By the way, vey much useful information is contained in the answers to this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work